How does freezing of ideal solution actually happens?
I tried thinking on how the ideal solution of a non-volatile solute and volatile solvent would freeze but I can't get to an conclusion. For simplicity, I will consider the solvent to be water here.
I know that addition of non-volatile solute leads to depression in freezing point (let's say it is 0.2°C here).
But how does the freezing actually happens.
Question 1:Does some water starts freezing just at 0°C or it starts freezing at -0.2°C.
Question 2:Is all water freezed at -0.2°C or it gradually freezes as we lower the temperature?
Question 3: How does the following question say that 'as ice separates freezing point goes down to -0.25°C'?

I look forward for a simple explanation without the use of chemical potential as I am a high school student.

The q. you cite already answers 1 and 2...

Under ideal conditions (very slow changes in temperature so that there is almost uniform temperature in the sample), water would start freezing at the calculated temperature.
Pure water freezes, so at that point the concentration of solute in the liquid increases, lowering the temperature required for freezing further. So then you have to lower the temperature further to form more ice.
At some temperature, the concentration of solute in solution is so high that the solute will start coming out of solution. This saturated solution is the one with the larger possible freezing point depression for the specific system you are looking at.
I think that answers all three questions.

Would the already formed ice impact further freezing like the vapor pressure equilibrium or the calculation of depression of freezing point as solute concentration increases?

Surely it will. Maybe Karsten should have said something to that effect. Maybe he did, but there is no way of knowing that, because who in their right mind would read through the entirety of four paragraphs of text.

@IvanNeretin Beware, the snark leads to the Dark Side!

The amount of ice doesn’t matter as long there is some formed.

Ok I got the concept.

The cryoscopy law stated that : $\pu{\Delta T = - K·c}$, where $\pu{K}$ is an unknown constant, and $\pu{c}$ is the concentration of solute. If the volume of the solution is $\pu{V_o = 100 mL}$, the concentration $\pu{c_o}$ of the solute is $\pu{x/100 = 0.01 x}$ mol/mL, and $\pu{\Delta T = - 0.2}$°C. This means that $\pu{K = 0.2°/0.01 x = 20/x}$ °C $\pu{mL mol^{-1}}$
The problem is to find the volume of solution V', such that the new concentration $\pu{c' = x/V'}$  is such that it implies $\pu{\Delta T' = - 0.25}$. Using the same formula  $$\pu{-0.25 = \Delta T' = Kc' = -\frac{20}{x} c'}$$ $$\pu{x/V' = c' = 0.25 x/20 = 0.25 \frac{5x}{100} = 1.25 c_o = 1.25 x/V_o}$$
$$\pu{V' = \frac{V_o}{1.25} = \frac{100 mL}{1.25} = 80 mL}$$ So this means that the solution has lost $20$ mL or $20$ g liquid water, which have been transformed into ice.
